# Looking for a convenient way to install Turtlebot from source

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-fuerte, source, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there an easy way to install the Turtlebot source code and its dependencies, in a similar manner to rosinstall with desktop or desktop-full ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35894/looking-for-a-convenient-way-to-install-turtlebot-from-source/) by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 995 on 2012-06-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-06-07**:
For fuerte??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
udo apt-get install ros-electric-turtlebot
```

and you have many different packages to install. They'll be added to

```
/opt/ros/electric/stacks
```

It is obvious that you can change electric for any ros release you want.

---

Originally posted by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) with karma: 318 on 2012-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2012-06-06**:
Indeed, but I'm not thinking of the binary installer.  It is possible to check out the latest Turtlebot code from the repository, but there are also various unmet dependencies and trying to check out all of those individually is quite arduous.

**Comment by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on 2012-06-06**:
if you want there's a command to install all the dependencies.

**Comment by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on 2012-06-06**:
rosdep-install.
What I do is rosmake --rosdep-install in the package and that's all.

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2012-06-06**:
rosdep-install doesn't seem to work in fuerte.  Is it deprecated?

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-06-06**:
Installation of turtlebot from the source is suggested. Its not too much dependent on the other packages that are not default in the ros. I assume joystick_drivers would be the package were the dependency issue might come.

**Comment by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on 2012-06-06**:
no idea, I don't use fuerte...

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2012-06-06**:
joystick_drivers is also dependent upon other packages not included by using rosinstall with desktop-full, so I was just wondering whether there was some more convenient way of doing this other than going package hunting.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-06-07**:
Even i haven't had hands on fuerte yet. Please update your question "looking for a convenient way" and also mention fuerte as the version of ros being used. I guess pros  will look at it and add something to the tutorials. Hunting is what i did when i installed. Its not that arduous either.